# map is not rendering the ui elements in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

What would be the best way to `render` out the todos object when that object is updated?  I've tried mapping through it, but it returns nothing with errors.

Code:

```js
import React from 'react';
const Todo = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return ({todos: []})
    },

    newTodo(e) {
        let today = new Date();
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
          console.log(this.state.todos)
          this.setState({
              todos: this.state.todos.concat({title: e.target.value, date: today})
          })
        }
    },

    delTodo(e) {},

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="panel panel-default">
                <div className="panel-heading">Todo List Creator</div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="enter todo name" className="form-control" onKeyPress={this.newTodo}/>
                </div>
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {this.state.todos.map((td, index) => {
                        <li key={index} className="list-group-item">
                            <strong>{td.name}</strong><br/>
                            {td.date}
                        </li>
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default Todo
```

Comment: can you show where you are using map to render the todo items ?

Comment: i guess that would have helped :D

Comment: i updated the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not returning anything inside `map` body, with `map` if you don't return anything it will return `undefined` by default.

Use this:

```
<ul className="list-group"> 
    {this.state.todos.map((td, index) => { 
        return <li key={index} className="list-group-item"> 
                    <strong>{td.name}</strong>
                    <br/> 
                    {td.date.toDateString()} 
               </li> 
        }) 
    } 
</ul>
```

Or you can write it like this also without using the `{}`:

```
<ul className="list-group"> 
    {this.state.todos.map((td, index) => (
           <li key={index} className="list-group-item"> 
                 <strong>{td.name}</strong>
                 <br/> 
                 {td.date.toDateString()}
           </li> 
       )) 
    } 
</ul>
```

**Note:**

We can't render any `object/array` inside `jsx` directly, since date is an object so you need to convert that into `string` by using `toDateString()` or any other `date` method.

Check the working todo example:

```js
const Todo = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return ({todos: []})
    },

    newTodo(e) {
        let today = new Date();
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
          this.setState({
              todos: this.state.todos.concat({title: e.target.value, date: today})
          })
        }
    },

    delTodo(index) {
       let todos = this.state.todos.slice();
       todos.splice(index, 1);
       this.setState({todos})
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="panel panel-default">
                <div className="panel-heading">Todo List Creator</div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="enter todo name" className="form-control" onKeyPress={this.newTodo}/>
                </div>
                <ul className="list-group"> 
                    {this.state.todos.map((td, index) => { 
                        return <li key={index} className="list-group-item"> 
                                  <strong>{td.title}</strong>  
                                  <button onClick={() => this.delTodo(index)}>delete</button>
                                  <br/> 
                                  {td.date.toDateString()} 
                               </li> 
                        }) 
                    } 
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Todo/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Check this snippet for `map`:

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

let b = a.map(el => {
   if(el % 2)
      return el;
});

console.log(b);
```

Comment: when i use return i get the "Objects are not valid as a React child" error in the console.

Comment: reason is, you are rendering the **date object** directly inside jsx and we can't render object/array directly, convert that into string by using `toDateString()` or any other date method, use this: `{td.date.toDateString()}`

Comment: i need to be able to delete the todo now.

Comment: that was not ur ques :), check the updated answer with working todo app including delete functionality, run the snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the arrow function to return a value use `()` instead of `{}`

```
{this.state.todos.map((td, index) => (
    <li key={index} className="list-group-item">
       <strong>{td.name}</strong><br/>
       {td.date}
    </li>
))
```