# Array.map object not displaying to the view?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an array stored in my redux store, but when I call `notifications.map((x, i) => {}` nothing actually renders to the view... however if I `console.log` `x` to the console then they print....

How do I get my array contents to render to the view?

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {List, ListItem} from 'material-ui/List'

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    notifications: state.notificationsReducer.notifications,
    errorMessage: state.notificationsReducer.errorMessage
  }
}

const notifications = ({notifications, errorMessage}) => {
  notifications.map((x, i) => {
    console.log(x.title)
  })
  return (
    <List>
      {notifications.map((x, i) => {
        <ListItem key={i} primaryText={x.title} />
      })}
    </List>
  )
}

const Notifications = connect(mapStateToProps)(notifications)
export default Notifications
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trying to render a react state object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008700/trying-to-render-a-react-state-object)

Comment: You need to return the list in your map function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the brackets of arrow function inside the `map`.

```
<List>
  {notifications.map((x, i) => 
    <ListItem key={i} primaryText={x.title} />
  )}
</List>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body

> I Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block
>   body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is needed, and an implicit
>   return is attached. In a block body, you must use an explicit return
>   statement.

Answer (score 1):

you have to return a value from the function to get the result you want

```
  return (
    <List>
      {notifications.map((x, i) => {
        return <ListItem key={i} primaryText={x.title} />
      })}
    </List>
  )
```

or simply by not opening a curly brackets in the first place (implicit return)

```
  return (
    <List>
      {notifications.map((x, i) =>
           <ListItem key={i} primaryText={x.title} />
      )}
    </List>
  )
```